# How can I generate anchored headings in Google Apps Script for Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script

Headings generated by GAS cannot be externally linked to

I've created a google apps script, that extracts comments from a google doc (sourcedoc), and order them in a new document (commentdoc) according to user-supplied tags. If a commentdoc has already been created by a prior run of the script, that commentdoc is updated.

The comment-doc uses the supplied user-tags as headings

`var paragraph = body.appendParagraph(tagTitle)  .setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2)`

I'd like to be able to get an URL for any of these headings. That's quite easy to do with a manually created heading, but not with a heading generated by my script.

**How can I generate headings that has an anchor that can be linked to?**

PS. Bookmarks won't work. I tried attaching generated bookmarks to each heading as a workaround, thinking I could link to the bookmark instead, but since the bookmarks are re-generated when I run the script a second time, the bookmark-id's are lost and replaced with new ones, and the URLs no longer work.

**Image:**

[image: the manually created heading has an anchor, the generated does not]

Comment: This is a reported issue, you can read more about it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761940).

Comment: Conclusion: At this point in time, it's not possible to create links to script-generated headings. 

Thanks Giselle